# Is it possible to print a large number of digits of a floating point number with gmp?

Tags: floating-point, precision, gmp

I would like to print

1589128402970546000515214676475308953824987995059891920501615931630880

[numbers of decimal expansion of ratio](http://mathr.co.uk/blog/2014-10-13_converting_fractions_to_strings_of_digits.html) :

33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562/237142198758023568227473377297792835283496928595231875152809132048206089502588927

I try to do it with gmp library :

```
// gcc p.c -lgmp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{       



     mpf_set_default_prec(1024); // set default precision in bits


    // declare   
    mpz_t zn;
    mpz_t zd;
    mpq_t q;
    mpf_t fn;
    mpf_t fd; 
    mpf_t f; // f=float(q=n/d)

    // init
    mpz_init (zn);
    mpz_init (zd);
    mpq_init (q);
    mpf_init2 (fn, 794564201485273000257607338237654476912493997529945960250807965815440 ); 
    mpf_init (fd); 
    mpf_init (f); 

    // set
    mpz_set_str(zn, "33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562", 10 ); // 
    // mpz_set_ui(n,33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562);   warning: integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default]
    mpz_set_str(zd, "237142198758023568227473377297792835283496928595231875152809132048206089502588927", 10);
    mpq_set_str(q, "33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562/237142198758023568227473377297792835283496928595231875152809132048206089502588927", 10);

    mpf_set_z(fn, zn);
    mpf_set_z(fd, zd);



    //
    mpf_div(f, fn, fd);

    // print result 
    gmp_printf ("  decimal floating point number : %.Ff \n", f); //

    // clear  
    mpz_clear (zn);
    mpz_clear (zd);
    mpq_clear(q);
    mpf_clear (fn);
    mpf_clear (fd);
    mpf_clear (f);

    return 0;
```

}

But the result is only 22 decimal digits :

decimal floating point number : 0.142857142857142857143

How should I do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the result is not good?"  Your problem statement needs to be more specific.

Comment: The result is listed now. Thx for pointing it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enhance precision (i.e. mantissa bits) to get more decimal digits. As [GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html#Floating_002dpoint-Functions) states (emphasis mine):

> The mantissa of each float has a **user-selectable precision**, limited
>   only by available memory. Each variable has its own precision, and
>   that can be increased or decreased at any time.

By default it chooses 64 bits for mantissa, and essentially what you get is about:

`dig10 = floor(dig2/log2(10))`,

thus you had only about 19 significant, decimal digits at the beginning. By requesting more precision you simply get more of them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    mpz_t zn, zd;
    mpf_t fn, fd, f;

    mpf_set_default_prec(1024);

    mpz_init_set_str(zn, "33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562", 10);
    mpz_init_set_str(zd, "237142198758023568227473377297792835283496928595231875152809132048206089502588927", 10);

    mpf_init(fn); mpf_init(fd); mpf_init(f);

    mpf_set_z(fn, zn);
    mpf_set_z(fd, zd);

    mpf_div(f, fn, fd);

    gmp_printf ("decimal floating point number: %.Ff\n", f);

    return 0;
}
```

results into:

```
decimal floating point number: 0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571470740220344350664325965724776508647459411274100902601628882480671861148592450467118250772869175909603098316903937670228712738977340379914830920623570643668473851880233962854802649343258544237378422095661611829666642751471587447213
```

If you want some fixed amount of decimal digits (and assuming that `zn/zd` quotient is zero) simply take use of above (or some more sophisticated) logarithmic equation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// gcc p.c -lgmp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{       



     mpf_set_default_prec(100024); // set default precision in bits


    // declare   
    mpz_t zn;
    mpz_t zd;
    mpq_t q;
    mpf_t fn;
    mpf_t fd; 
    mpf_t f; // f=float(q=n/d)

    // init
    mpz_init (zn);
    mpz_init (zd);
    mpq_init (q);
    mpf_init (fn) ; //794564201485273000257607338237654476912493997529945960250807965815440 ,100); 
    mpf_init (fd); 
    mpf_init (f); 

    // set
    mpz_set_str(zn, "33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562", 10 ); // 
    // mpz_set_ui(n,33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562);   warning: integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default]
    mpz_set_str(zd, "237142198758023568227473377297792835283496928595231875152809132048206089502588927", 10);
    //mpq_set_str(q, "33877456965431938318210482471113262183356704085033125021829876006886584214655562/237142198758023568227473377297792835283496928595231875152809132048206089502588927", 10);

    mpf_set_z(fn, zn);
    mpf_set_z(fd, zd);



    //
    mpf_div(f, fn, fd);

    // print result 
    printf (" ratio =  "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10,zn);  printf (" / ");     mpz_out_str(stdout, 10,zd);  printf (" \n "); 
    gmp_printf ("  decimal floating point number : %.Ff \n", f); //

    // clear  
    mpz_clear (zn);
    mpz_clear (zd);
    mpq_clear(q);
    mpf_clear (fn);
    mpf_clear (fd);
    mpf_clear (f);

    return 0;
```

}

Above code is better, but  if I need n decimal digits should I set precision to n*4 ?

Edit :

> I would like to print 1589128402970546000515214676475308953824987995059891920501615931630880 numbers ...

It is simply impossible because it is 10^71 numbers which  is more then chars ( letters) in [all books in the world](http://thenextweb.com/google/2010/08/05/how-many-books-are-in-the-world-google-actually-counted/) ( 10^8 books x [10^5  chars per book](http://thenextweb.com/google/2010/08/05/how-many-books-are-in-the-world-google-actually-counted/) )